# Nebular theme overwrite theme variables

Tags: nebular

I was trying to overwrite the corporate theme variables (nb-action colors) by setting the corresponding variables in my theme.scss file.

It looks as follows:

```
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/theming';
@import '~@nebular/theme/styles/themes/corporate';
$theme: ( actions-fg:#000000, actions-bg: #000000, actions-separator: #000000, color-fg: #000000, );
$nb-themes: nb-register-theme(( $theme), corporate, default);
```

The problem is that the colors of the nb-action(s) component do not change at all. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  // add your variables here like:
  actions-fg:#000000,
  actions-bg: #000000,
  actions-separator: #000000,
  color-fg: #000000,
), corporate, corporate);
```

and don't forget to change the `NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'corporate' })` part.
Here is a full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-kafw6m?file=src/themes.scss